# What is a breakpoint's role in the debugger

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just learning python and not understanding exactly the role of a breakpoints in python

Comment: if you google "breakpoint coding" you will get a load of good answers.

Answer (score 0):

A breakpoint let you stop the code execution to, for example, see the variables states or make a trace of code execution.

Debugger in python should be the same that in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints are super helpful in debugging your code and can help you get a snapshot of variables as the application is running.
It will stop the program and allow you to step through the program step by step.

> you can set breakpoints and type continue, or you can step through the
> statement using step or next (all these commands are explained below).
> The optional globals and locals arguments specify the environment in
> which the code is executed; by default the dictionary of the module
> **main** is used. (See the explanation of the exec statement or the eval() built-in function.)
>
> src: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html